# Using python to log into AWS Cognito and get a token, just like a human user

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I created a user pool in AWS Cognito, and am able to sign in from a browser.
I use this login to call a lambda function through api-gateway to create posts.
It is very handy that I can use the token to identify the user in the lambda itself, like so:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1")
    table = dynamodb.Table("posts")
    response = table.put_item(Item={
        "added_by": jwt.decode(event["headers"]["Authorization"], verify=False)['cognito:username'],
        "content": event["body"]["content"]
    })
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': response
    }
```

I would like to use the same lambda function through a python program that will be posting as well, using an identity from the same user pool (with username like 'python_bot')
Is there a way to sign into a Cognito userpool, using a username+password, and getting an access token using python? I didn't find anything that does that in boto3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an App Client for your app, not a user: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html

Comment: Thanks, that gave me a good direction. I ended up finding a real good explanation and example here: https://aws-blog.de/2020/01/machine-to-machine-authentication-with-cognito-and-serverless.html